# What is the opposite of onwards? "From 2000 [onwards]"

Tags: single-word-requests

If I want to talk about the years before 2000, can I say "backwards"?

I can only think of preceding, prior or previous

> The preceding/prior/previous years of 2000.
>   2000 and the prior/preceding/previous years.

But I want to have an exact sentence like the one in my question.

Edit:
Can you complete/correct my sentences?

> It was not popular from year 2000 _________. (previous years)
>   We didn't have this kind of policy from 2000 _______. (previous years)

Thank you.

Comment: You could say "until 2000", unless you want to work backwards in time.

Comment: State the noun first: “... the years prior to/preceding 2000.”

Comment: Thank you. I edited my question. So it's not possible to have the same sentence construction as "year 2000 onwards"?

Comment: In *Mad Max: Beyond Thunderdome*, they used the phrase *from history back*. I always liked the sound of it. But I wouldn't use it. You could say *in 2000 and before* or *in 2000 or before*, depending on the specific sentence.

Comment: Your problem is the use of "from" as it implies forward movement. You need to use something like "up to" or "until".

Comment: *backwards* works if you want an exact filler antonym for *onwards*.

Answer (score 1):

We normally say "through 2000" or "up through 2000" (or sometimes with "the year 2000" instead of just "2000" if the latter might not be clear enough in the context, or "December 2000" for both clarity and more explicit precision).

We also often say "until 2000", but that doesn't necessarily mean that 2000 is included: "until 2000" can mean that the cutoff is the very *beginning* of 2000, or the very *end* of 2000, or anywhere in between. In your case, it sounds like you want to make clear that 2000 *is* included, so "through" or "up through" is a better bet.

---

For the example sentences you've added, which have negative polarity ("not popular", "didn't have"), I'd recommend "until after":

> It was not popular from year 2000 _________. (previous years)

"It was not popular until after the year 2000."

(Note, by the way, that it's "the year 2000", not just "year 2000". I'm not sure why.)

> We didn't have this kind of policy from 2000 _______. (previous years)

"We didn't have this kind of policy until after 2000."

Comment: OP wrote "I want to talk about the years before 2000". I have only ever heard "through" used when talking about a *range* of something, like 1900 through 2000.

Comment: Thank you. I edited my question. So it's not possible to have the same sentence construction as "year 2000 onwards"?

Comment: @turvadze_sheik: "From X" implies that X is the starting-point rather than the ending-point; so, for example, you can't say "from 2000 to 1900" unless the context actually involves moving backward from 2000 to 1900.

Comment: @WeatherVane has it:  “We didn’t have this kind of policy before 2000.”  “It was not popular before 2000”

Comment: @Jim: Those sentences have the wrong meaning IMHO; maybe you meant to write "before 2001"?